# What is this language for set theory and good MATH books to learn it from?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, first-order-logic

I plan on studying (or at least attempting to study) Levy's book **Basic Set Theory**  and Jech's book **Set Theory** or any other more "advanced book on set theory" one day. However, I have noticed that all these books use language of the form:

> $\forall y, ((\forall t, t\in y \implies (t\in z \land\phi(t)) )\land (\forall t, (t\in z\land \phi(t)) \implies t\in y)) \implies P(y)$.

and

> $$\forall x \forall p \exists y [\forall u (u \in y \leftrightarrow (u \in x \& \phi(u,p)))].$$

I am familiar with ZFC Axioms however i am not familiar with them stated in this form. I have questions such as what does "$\phi(u,p)$" really mean? What constitutes a formula in set theory? How do i read these statements above and produce them myself?

However my question (for the purpose of this post) is are there any good books that teach you this language above strictly for the purposes of doing set theory? And that will answer my questions stated above? I believe this language is "first order logic" but I am more interested in math books not books on logic.

Comment: I think you need first order logic and some model theory to study advanced set theory. You may want to try Hrbacek and Jech's other book called Introduction to Set theory which goes at a gentle pace and does not have much prerequisites.

Comment: Every introductory book about Mathematical Logic will do.

Comment: I like Kunen's *Foundations of Mathematics*.

Comment: Yeah Kunen’s is good?! I’ll take that advice!

Comment: Stephen Kleene’s Introduction to Metamathematics is a brilliant book for learning first order logic and Gödel’s Incompleteness Theorems.  From there I recommend Kunen’s Set Theory or Jech.